# How to properly align left and right children elements in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I need a bit of advice on the two questions below:

1. How do I properly align the below text elements left and right. Right now they are both aligned to the left side?
2. Is is possible to add some padding to the text on the right side?
3. Is is possible to make the left expanded class 70% of the screen size and the left on 30%?

This is my code:

```
List<Widget> keyList = new List<Widget>();      
keyList.add(new Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
        new Expanded(
            child: Text("Aligned left")
                ),
        new Expanded(
            child: Text("Aligned right") //Now it's aligned to the left
                            )
            ],
));
```

Comment: Set flex properties of expanded first 7 second 3. Wrap desirable text widget in padding widget and set needed EdgeInsets.

Comment: Changing the car motor oil is the most basic car maintenance as well. Max 2 min searching on Youtube. Yet people go to the mechanics for this right? There is a reason for it, same as there is a reason for my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `TextAlign`
2. Use `Padding`
3. Use [`flex`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible/flex.html) values of `7` and `3`

```dart
List<Widget> keyList = new List<Widget>();      
keyList.add(
  Row(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        flex: 3
        child: Text("Aligned left")
      ),
      Expanded(
        flex: 7,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
          child: Text(
            "Aligned right",
             textAlign: TextAlign.right,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ],
);
```

If you don't want the padding to be included in the specified proportions, use a `SizedBox` with a width at the end of the row instead of padding.